# Finding the largest inscribed axis aligned rectangle in a convex polygon

Tags: computational-geometry

I need to compute the largest inscribed axis aligned rectangle in a convex polygon so I've been following the algorithms laid out in this [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ef02/249725c8e8e42655d39ef461d9a375f69bae.pdf). Using the prune and search method I can narrow the polygon down to the relevant vertices and edges for the two and three vertex rectangles. What isn't clear is: how is the largest inscribed rectangle constructed from those vertices and edges?

I also found [this website](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Eathens/cs507/Projects/2003/DanielSud/) which goes into a bit more detail on the algorithms covered in the paper. It still isn't clear how the rectangles are formed as for the two corner case it says

> If an edge remains on both A and C, from lemma 1, we consider this to be four instances of the case with an edge and a vertex

I simply don't see how there would be four instances as opposed to two. A is a corner and C an edge and C is a corner and A is an edge. Not sure what the two other cases referenced would be.

Additionally, in the three corner case the website says

> Other candidates will be contain at least one vertex so we can examine all six of them (two for each edge in A, B and C) and keep only the valid ones

Which once again seems to be double the amount I would except but this is probably the same issue as the two corner case. It also mentions that

> First, there may exist a solution that contains no vertices of P.  For this candidate, we need to extend the the edges containing a,b, and c into lines that will intersect to form a triangle.  If we parametrize the area as a function of the position of b, we get that the area is maximized when b is located exactly in the middle of its corresponding triangle edge

I have tested this approach; however, the answer it produces seems wrong just by inspection i.e. I used a polygon defined by (0, 0), (1, 3), (5, 2), (3, -1) and the rectangle produced had an area of ~5.8 whereas by inspection I could produce rectangles with an area of ~6.8.

EDIT:
Looked into this a bit more and it seems like the area being maximized when b is in the middle of its corresponding triangle edge likely comes from [here](http://mathcountsnotes.blogspot.com/2013/05/the-largest-rectangle-inscribed-in-any.html?m=1) but that seems to suggest area is maximized when the point lies in the middle of the two sides of the triangle as opposed to the base. I don't see how it is possible to assume the b segment isn't the base of the triangle and thus the point should lie at the midpoint of the a or c segment (although in the example I gave that point is outside the polygon in all cases so that doesn't seem t work either).

EDIT2:
Unfortunately haven't had a lot of time to look into this problem but I suspect [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.47.6968&rep=rep1&type=pdf) describes the process to compute the largest rectangle for the three corner case using different terminology.

> Three Dependent Sliding Contacts: The case of three dependent sliding contacts is depicted in Figure 4(b). It is dealt with in a manner similar to the case of two dependent sliding contacts. See [12] for details

Which points to [this earlier article](http://nrs.harvard.edu/urn-3:HUL.InstRepos:27030936) by the same authors. Once I have time to read through that paper I'll most likely provide another update.